# Apollo: Loading state between re-renders of the component

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, react-hooks

I have the following component.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useQuery } from 'react-apollo-hooks';

import Table from 'components/Table';
import { useQueryParams } from 'customHooks';
import { LOCATIONS } from 'graphql/queries';

const useLocations = ({ filters, max, sorting }) => {
    const variables = { max, filters, sorting };
    return useQuery(LOCATIONS, { variables, fetchPolicy: 'network-only' });
};

const Search = ({ filters, sorting }) => {
    // Gets the value for the parameter "max" from the URL, with default 100
    const { max, updateURLParam } = useQueryParams({ max: 100 });

    const { data, error, loading } = useLocations({ filters, sorting, max });

    if (loading && !data.myData) return <div>Loading</div>;

    if (error) return <div>Error</div>;

    // Update the URL parameter "max"
    // Example
    // Before: https://localhost:3000/table?max=100
    // After: https://localhost:3000/table?max=200
    const handleReachBottom = () => updateURLParam({ max: max + 100 });

    return <Table.Locations data={data} onReachBottom={handleReachBottom} />;
};

export default Search;
```

The behaviour that I was expecting is following:

1. Displays "Loading"
2. Displays a table with the data
3. Scrolls to the bottom of the table
4. While fetching the new data, the table is still being displayed
5. When the data is fetched, the table is updated

Before I was using the [Query component](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries/) from apollo, and it was working exactly like that. But when I switched to the [react-apollo-hooks](https://github.com/trojanowski/react-apollo-hooks) package, the behaviour changed to this one:

1. Displays "Loading"
2. Displays a table with the data
3. Scrolls to the bottom of the table
4. **Displays "Loading"**
5. When the data is fetched, the table is updated

Why could this be?

**UPDATE**

This is how I was using it before:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Query } from 'react-apollo';


import Table from 'components/Table';
import useQueryParams from 'customHooks/useQueryParams';

const Locations = ({ filters, max, sorting, children }) => {
    const variables = { max, sorting };

    return (
        <Query {...{ variables }} query={LOCATIONS} fetchPolicy='network-only'>
            {children}
        </Query>
    );
};


const Search = ({ filters, sorting }) => {
    const { max, updateURLParam } = useQueryParams({ max: 100 });

    return (
        <MyClient.Locations {...{ filters, sorting, max }}>
            {({ data, loading, error }) => {
                if (loading && !data.myData) return <div>Loading</div>;

                if (error) return <div>Error</div>;

                const handleReachBottom = () => updateURLParam({ max: max + 100 });


                return (
                    <Table.Locations
                        data={data}
                        onReachBottom={handleReachBottom}
                    />
                );
            }}
        </MyClient.Locations>
    );
};

export default Search;
```

Comment: How were you using the query component previously? Because here loading would be set to true while refetching and `if (loading) return <div>Loading</div>;` would return the loading div

Comment: I updated the question with that info

Comment: Not sure if this would work, but you can try `{ notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: false }` as the second argument to the useQuery hook.

Comment: No, that didnt solve anything

Comment: I updated the question using `if (loading && !data.myData)`, which makes sense, but the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before with `react-apollo-hooks`, I feel like the behaviour with re-fetching, variables and fetchPolicy is subtly different to standard Apollo. I never got to the bottom of it.

The way I got around it was don't use the `loading` prop, instead use the presence of the data itself to decide what to do. This approach works while refetching

```
const [data, setData] = useState(null)

const res = useLocations({ filters, sorting, max });

useEffect(() => {
  if (Object.keys(res.data || {}).length > 0) {
    setData(res.data)
  }
}, [res.data])

if (!data) return <div>Loading</div>
```

Comment: If I use `if (loading && !data.myData) return <div>Loading</div>;` I still get the same problem. Seems like `data` resets to `{}` everytime it re-fetches.

Comment: Yes data gets reset to `{}` ... so my solution above is to cache it locally with a `useState` hook. You only update that local cache when the data _isnt_ `{}`.

Comment: I ended up making a custom hook to handle it, here you go https://gist.github.com/jedrichards/c02af3496f4e304b720a9624db647dfb

Comment: Wow... O.o that's nice